How to Fix "unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.format" Error in Python
I'm trying to put 4 decimals, but I get this error: "unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.format"
Here's the code:
best_fit = f'y = {model.coef_[0]:.4f}x{model.intercept_:+4f}'

Please help me. I don't understand the reason of this error

+4f is probably meant to be .4f or +.4f, depending on whether or not you want the sign included in the formatting.
